# how to import Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, overlay, libs

i'm new in Android Development and try to import some libraries in Android Studio for example.

```
import android.content.om.OverlayInfo;
```

if i try to use it i got the message "cannot resolve symol 'om'".
i tried to copy some file in into the project but i still got the same messange

how do i do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies Tab -> Add module dependency (scope = compile)

Where the module dependency is the project library Android folder.

Answer (score 0):

**There are three ways to do it**

1. Adding Gradle Dependency

//for example i'm using picasso
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

2. Adding .jar/.aar Dependency

In some cases, we don’t get the Gradle dependency of the library. Instead, we get only the .jar/.aar file. In such case you can follow the below steps:

- Find the .jar/.aar file and download it.
- Then copy the file from the downloaded location and go to Android Studio.
- Go to the App module and paste the file inside the libs folder. (If you don’t see the libs folder, create a new directory inside the App module.)
- And then add this to Module app Gradle

  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude : ['*mock*.jar'])

3. Adding dependency as a module

- Go to File -> New -> Import Module -> Select the library path -> Finish.
- Then right-click on the App directory -> Open Module Settings -> Dependencies -> Click on + button inside Declared Dependencies -> Module Dependency -> Select your library -> Ok.